# Data entry form (search, add, edit, delete) for more than one row - google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to work with data entry for more than one row through a form in Google Sheet or a tool to add, search, modify and delete ?

Maybe the dialog form best for my order

First: Save Data button
Add a button in the form to add more than one data entry row at a time before saving
For example, adding more than one product type for a supplier

Second: When searching
Enter the supplier code in the cell (D3) to call all the supplier data rows from input and output

Third: When modification or deletion after the search
Allow selection to modify or delete a row from the called rows

[Example Form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZEyeLmCW9VpbucPPWO1uXoNGrjEE5d3WibERYwp8Y-8/copy)

[Source of the article](https://www.bpwebs.com/how-to-create-a-data-entry-form-in-google-sheet/)

[Form Proposal](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wroUrAFpXMOaH_tgEgkXXChvtqO4yi7ENyPhHPM9mw0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I would make the form a dialog.

Comment: Hello! Could you clarify what you mean with "work with data entry for more than one row"? Do you mean you want to add something like a button to add and remove input fields? Any information you add would be helpful!

Comment: Of course
When you add as you said
and When searching for data, the number of form fields is matched by the number of rows called to be modified or deleted as needed
Thanks for interest

Comment: Please explain exactly how you want these interactions to happen. Possibly, add a step-by-step description, explaining what fields need to be filled or fetched from the table.

Comment: @Cooper - OK .. Thank you for caring

Comment: @ZektorH - You are patient with me .. Thank you .. The question is explained above
.. The proposal form was modified to clarify the required in Form Proposal

Comment: The problem with your request is that it's just too broad.  Building a form of this nature including all of the required nuances takes a considerable amount of time and tweaking.  Your going to have to come up with a basic design on your own and when you have problems that are well defined then hopefully we can assist you at that time.  If your not experienced with JavaScript or Google Apps Script or you have never designed a user interface before perhaps you should consider hiring someone to help you.

Comment: Some priorities on an accounting/stock-management theme: 1) Develop some stock data, otherwise this is just a hypothetical. 2) Decide "why" you want to search by stock item , and what you want to do with the data, then develop an appropriate search form 3) Add one product per screen (unless you want to add  in bulk, in which case you wont use a screen anyway). 4) Don't delete stock, just make it inactive; the item  may be linked to sales/customer/supplier information. 5) do some research on multiple nested dropdowns (linking suppliers, products, etc). Ask technical questions as you go.